# SSIS Execute Analysis Services Task Error: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated

Tags: ssis, ssas

I have an ETL on SSIS fully running, and created cubes via SSAS with success, deployed and processed.

I can run the ETL, the process&deploy ssas via Visual Studio, all works

Now i'm trying to put the cube processing in the ETL, with "Analysis Services Processing Task", 3 of them: "process dimensions","process cubes","process database".

I get the error:

```
[Analysis Services Execute DDL Task] Error: The following system error occurred: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
```

With the two possible configurations of the connection to SSAS:

- If the ssis "Analysis Services Processing Task" is connected to the ssas project (that is in the same solution).
- And even when i change the connection in the "Connection Manager" to "Create a connection to a computer running Analysis Services", in which set the server: .\SQLSERVER2008R2, location blank,  integrated security, database catalog set, teste connection with success. Then i updated the configuration files with the connection string, just to be sure.

The only way around is to run etl tasks only, deploy the ssas project via Visual Studio (where i'm prompted to insert my windows user password!), then run the ssas tasks of the ssis package, after this the ssas task in ssis runs successfully.

UPDATE: I've changed the connection to windows authentication, test is ok. But still same error when i run the ssis task...i've never seen nothing like this

Answer (score 1):

How are you executing your SSIS package? That error is usually related when running through a windows task, and bound to a security policy having the "Run whether user is logged on or not" security option on the General Tab. I am referring to the following : 
[image]

In the case of running through a task, you can try disabling the policy and see if the problem still occurs 
[image]

However it is not clear what you are using the execute the SSIS.

Comment: sorry, i didn't clear that up, i'm executing the SSIS ETL package via Visual Studio.

Still, i checked and the policy is already disabled.

The only way around is to run etl tasks only, deploy the ssas project via Visual Studio (where i'm prompted to insert my windows user password!), then run the ssas tasks of the ssis package.

Comment: Try accessing the analysis server with the full host name, and also by IP address.

Comment: i'll try with the hostname, but don't need do test with ip address, because this is all the the same local machine

Comment: i tried "host"\SQLSERVER2008R2 test connection ok, still same error when executing

Answer (score 1):

This does not qualifies as an answer, more of a workaround.

The problem is that visual studio does not store or retrieve the password in the data source of a SSAS. I tried checking the "save password", manually insert the password in the dtsConfig file, but still get the error, and the password is blank in the edit section of the connection.

What i did was generate the xmla via Deployment Wizard, which as to be executed manually the first time before the ETL runs, this way my SSAS tasks in the SSIS run with no stress.

Side note: SSAS & SSIS are like the ugly cousins of microsoft developments tools, they are far behind the other project types/technologies microsoft has.